# spatial set operations in Apache Spark

Tags: spatial, apache-spark

Has anyone been able to do spatial operations with @ApacheSpark? e.g. intersection of two sets that contain line segments?

I would like to intersect two sets of lines.

Here is a 1-dimensional example:

The two sets are:

- A = {(1,4), (5,9), (10,17),(18,20)}
- B = {(2,5), (6,9), (10,15),(16,20)}

The result intersection would be:
intersection(A,B) = {(1,1), (2,4), (5,5), (6,9), (10,15), (16,17), (18,20)}

A few more details:
- sets have ~3 million items
- the lines in a set cover the entire range

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I'm a little confused here what is a line set?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. Line sets are sets that contain line segments with a start and end coordinate.

Comment: Don't forget to vote and accept answers, when asking questions on SO :)

Comment: noted :) (on the same theme, don't forget to favorite interesting questions...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to parallelize this would be to create a grid of some size, and group line segments by the grids they belong to.

So for a grid with sizes n, you could `flatMap` pairs of coordinates (segments of line segments), to create `(gridId, ( (x,y), (x,y) ))` key-value pairs.

The segment `(1,3), (5,9)` would be mapped to `( (1,1), ((1,3),(5,9) )` for a grid size 10 - that line segment only exists in grid "slot" `1,1` (the grid from 0-10,0-10). If you chose a smaller grid size, the line segment would be flatmapped to multiple key-value pairs, one for each grid-slot it belongs to.

Having done that, you can `groupByKey`, and for each group, calculation intersections as normal.

It wouldn't exactly be the most efficient way of doing things, especially if you've got long line segments spanning multiple grid "slots", but it's a simple way of splitting the problem into subproblems that'll fit in memory.

Comment: The grid solution indeed came to mind. How does this relate to with the partitioning of the RDD that is done by spark?

Comment: `groupByKey` would group (and partition) line segments (line segment segments, I guess...) by key - the key being the grid "id". So you can somewhat control the partitioning by changing the grid size.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of my Python code that implements the partitioning of the sets of ranges into a grid and working on each cell. http://pastebin.com/GzgzUvn3.
It does the trick, but there is room for optimization, e.g. choosing the correct grid size. Any ideas here?

Comment: It all depends on how exact you want to be. The simplest approach would probably be to find `xGridLen = (max_x - min_x)/wanted_amount_of_grids`. You could further improve this by counting the amount of line segments in each group (using `reduceByKey`), and further re-adjust your grid-size based on that. Do this iteratively (or accept this first adjustment) to find a suitable grid size. Finally, if your input data is large, it would likely make sense to `.sample` your data before measuring and estimating a good grid size.

Comment: Another, likely better approach, would be to create histograms of points on the x and y axis for a `.sample`, and calculate grid sizes that will roughly contain the same amount of elements. That way, you'll hopefully be able to create partitions with roughly equal amounts of line segments.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this with a full `cartesian` join of the two RDDs, but this would become incredibly slow at large scale. If your problem is smallish, sure, this is an easy and cheap approach. Just emit the overlap, if any, between every pair in the join.

To do better, I imagine that you can solve this by sorting the sets by start point, and then walking through both at the same time, matching one's current interval versus another and emitting overlaps. Details left to the reader.

You can almost solve this by first mapping each tuple `(x,y)` in A to something like `((x,y),'A')` or something, and the same for B, and then taking the `union` and `sortBy` the x values. Then you can `mapPartitions` to encounter a stream of labeled segments and implement your algorithm.

This doesn't quite work though since you would miss overlaps between values at the ends of partitions. I can't think of a good simple way to take care of that off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks. I thought of sifting through the cartesian product of the sets, but since they are large sets (~3 million records), it does not look feasible. Also, would doing so benefit from Spark's power and do stuff in parallel?

Comment: Yeah, cartesian product is a non-starter at that scale, even though it would be quite parallelizable. If your intervals are smallish, I suppose you could generate (x,(a,b)) for all a <= x <= b. This collects the subset of pairs that can possibly overlap. However it wouldn't work for large ranges or continuous ranges.

Comment: Generating (x,(a,b)) for all a <= x <= b would increase my data by a factor of 1000, so I guess although it is a good idea, it is not feasible in my case.